# Check if data frame exists

Tags: r, dataframe

What is the preferred way to check that data frame exists given you have data frame name as string? I can think of:

```
df_name <- 'iris'

# Option 1
tryCatch(is.data.frame(get(df_name)), error=function(cond) FALSE)

# Option 2
if (exists(df_name)) is.data.frame(get(df_name)) else FALSE
```

Comment: I would vote for the second one. but if you want to wrap it in a function then either the 'iris' or the `df_name` need to be changed so the same name is being used.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The second option can be shortened to

```
exists(df_name) && is.data.frame(get(df_name))
```

The operator `&&` allows lazy evaluation, i.e., the second statement is only evaluated if the first one returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

A warning to anyone who (like me) stumbles on the accepted answer years later and carelessly misinterprets `df_name` as the name of a data frame...it is not. It is a string, as clearly stated by the OP.

If using an actual data frame name, you must place the data frame name in quotes in both cases:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)), c("a","b"))

exists(df) && is.data.frame(get(df))
Error in exists(df) : invalid first argument

exists("df") && is.data.frame(get(df))
Error in get(df) : invalid first argument

exists("df") && is.data.frame(get("df"))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

exists("df_name") would give a TRUE (if the data frame exist) and FALSE (if it doesn't). So why bother? The trycatch statement in the first response did not work. It's output was FALSE all the time.

Comment: Perhaps your response only checks whether an object exists rather than whether that object exists as a data frame?

Comment: Also, the `tryCatch` statement returned `TRUE` for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
ifelse(any(ls() %in% "a"), is.data.frame(get("a")),FALSE)
```

Comment: This seems to be both an inappropriate use of `ifelse()` and fails to extend the "search" to available system datasets that may not be in the global environment.